# Change object fields after object creation in java

Tags: java

I have 3 class First, Second, and Third, Third class has a field name, I am creating an object of three classes, Now after the creation of the object I want to change the name of the Third class field from "john" to "sam", How can I update that without creating a new Third class object.

```
  public class First {
    List<Second> second;

    public List<Second> getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(List<Second> second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Second

```
public class Second {
    protected Third third;

    public Third getThird() {
        return third;
    }

    public void setThird(Third third) {
        this.third = third;
    }
}
```

Third

```
public class Third {
    protected String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Third{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Third third = new Third();
        third.setName("john");

        Second second = new Second();
        List<Second> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(second);
        second.setThird(third);
        First first = new First();
        first.setSecond(list);
         // How can I set change Third object name from john to Sam

        System.out.println(first.second.get(0).third.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: You change the name to Sam the same way you changed it to "john": `third.setName("Sam");`

Comment: In real code I don't have access to set the fields

Comment: If you don't have access to the fields then don't set them! There is a reason the developer didn't give you access.

Answer (score 0):

When you have instance of `First` class, then you can use getter to get required object and then use it to the the field:

```
first.getSecond().get(0).getThird().setName("Sam");
```

***P.S.** This is not safe, because you can get `NPE` or e.g. `second` list could be empty.*